# Не работают стили для active класса NavLink (React)

Tags: reactjs

Не понимаю, почему так происходит, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
 <div className={styles.item}>
    <NavLink
      className={({ isActive, isPending }) =>
        isPending ? "pending" : isActive ? "active1" : ""
      }
      to="/Profile"
    >
      Profile
    </NavLink>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.item}>
    <NavLink
      className={({ isActive, isPending }) =>
        isPending ? "pending" : isActive ? "active1" : ""
      }
      to="/Dialogs"
    >
      Dialogs
    </NavLink>
  </div>
```

Через f12 при клике на ссылку появляется класс active1, но мой стили для этого класса не применяются.

```
.sidebar {
  grid-area: s;
  background-color: aqua;
  max-height: 400px;
}
.item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.item a {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s color;
}
.item a.active {
  color: rgb(41, 248, 0);
}

.item--padding {
  margin-top: 20px;
}





"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

Comment: Вполне возможно "твои стили" имеют меньший приоритет, чем "другие стили"... Или в "твоих стилях" есть синтаксические ошибки и браузер их "отбрасывает".